# Possible to create a command to open clementine and have it create a playlist of 50 random songs?

Tags: clementine

So I'm trying to figure out how to make Clementine automatically create a playlist of 50 songs from my library when I open it. Is this possible? I'm using the latest ubuntu btw.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not without some coding at least for this solution.

What you would do is write a script that would look at your library, pick X songs by filename (i would so this by using `ls` folder, and the parsing the file locations with a "random function" like milliseconds.) When this parsing is complete, it should have stored it as a single string of files seperated by a space. This string would be tagged onto

`clementine --append "your-string-of-music-"`

All these pieces would be in one executable script.

Maybe there already is a random functions for this. If not, good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm actually trying to learn how to code so this may actually push me to continue learning. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047773/how-to-play-mp3-songs-randomly-by-searching-for-them-recursively-in-a-directory):

```
find `pwd -P` -name "*.mp3" | sort --random-sort | head -n 50 | xargs -d '\n' clementine --append 2> /dev/null
```

`pwd` gives full path, and `-P` (`--physical`) avoid all symlinks.

Give `head` the number of files to append.